# Displaying Custom post type in Lightbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I am using the Lightbox Plus Colorbox Worpress plugin to try and display custom post types in a lighbox rather than on its own page.

I've used the following code where `lbp-inline-href-1` is the plugin functionality that puts the content in the lightbox:

```
<?php
//WordPress loop for custom post type
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=package&package-category=Kenya&posts_per_page=-1');

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a class="lbp-inline-link-1" href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<div style="display:none">

<div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding: 10px;background: #fff">

               <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
               <div class="content">
               <?php the_content(); ?>
               </div>

</div>
</div>  


<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The code partly works, where the content appears in the lightbox however all the posts titles link to the same first post i.e .when i click on the title of any of the posts, the all open a lightbox and show the same content-they all show the first post content.

Please help

Comment: You need to use unique id for both `a` and related content `div`. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623262/displaying-custom-post-type-in-lightbox/23623582#23623582)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not using unique id for each post. You can use following;

```
<?php
//WordPress loop for custom post type
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=package&package-category=Kenya&posts_per_page=-1');

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a class="lbp-inline-link-1" href="#post_<?php the_ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<div style="display:none">

<div id="post_<?php the_ID; ?>" style="padding: 10px;background: #fff">

               <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
               <div class="content">
               <?php the_content(); ?>
               </div>

</div>
</div>  


<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I have used the id of current post in `href` and `div` in order to open related post. For example;

```
<a class="lbp-inline-link-1" href="#post_23"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<div style="display:none">

<div id="post_23" style="padding: 10px;background: #fff">

               <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
               <div class="content">
               <?php the_content(); ?>
               </div>

</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, `post_23` matches

Comment: ..thanks but the above opens a blank modal..there is no content inside the modal windows?

Comment: @user2798091 could you please source code of lightbox? You see the div elements?